# Do I need to specify foreign keys in Ruby on Rails generators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, foreign-keys, generator

Here's my very small, basic test website use case I'm building:

```
A 'Posting' belongs to a 'User' and a 'User' can have many 'Posting's.
```

I know that in the database there has to be a foreign key relationship. Do I need to specify this foreign key in the generator?

```
rails generate Posting name:string body:text post_date:date User:User???
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rails g Posting name:string body:text post_date:date user:references
```

By the way, if your field type is string, you don't actually need to specify it's type - rails will set it to string by default.

Answer (score 2):

Just make it an integer with model name underscore id

```
rails g Post user_id:integer
```